# How to execute a js function on pageunload

Tags: javascript, php, html, onbeforeunload

I'm making a little game, and I want to save the score when the user leaves the page, I want to do this without jquery or another library, is this possible?

I save the score by executing a javascript function that creates a form and automatically submits it, so it's data is being send to the server:

```
function sendData() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method","post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "submit.php");
    form.setAttribute("id","returnForm");

      var formContent1 = document.createElement("input");
      formContent1.setAttribute("name","gamesPlayed");
      formContent1.value = gamesPlayed;  //parameter 1

      var formContent2 = document.createElement("input");
      formContent2.setAttribute("name","totalSteps");
      formContent2.value = totalTurns;   //parameter 2 

    form.appendChild(formContent1);
    form.appendChild(formContent2);
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  document.getElementById("returnForm").submit();
}
```

I found a few things such as, this function will pop up a window with 'are you really sure you want to leave this page',

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return false; 
  }
```

But when I try to put my 'sendData()' function in it, it doesn't work:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    sendData();
  }
```

Even if I put the entire function in it:

```
  window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      var form = document.createElement("form");
      form.setAttribute("method","post");
      form.setAttribute("action", "submit.php");
      form.setAttribute("id","returnForm");

        var formContent1 = document.createElement("input");
        formContent1.setAttribute("name","gamesPlayed");
        formContent1.value = gamesPlayed;  //parameter 1

        var formContent2 = document.createElement("input");
        formContent2.setAttribute("name","totalSteps");
        formContent2.value = totalTurns;   //parameter 2 

      form.appendChild(formContent1);
      form.appendChild(formContent2);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    document.getElementById("returnForm").submit();
  }
```

Comment: What happens if you run `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    alert("Goodbye World")
  }`?

Comment: Try adding a `console.log()` at the start of the `sendData` function and see if it logs with the two methods you tried with `window.onberforeunload`

Comment: It might not be allowed in Chrome and Mozilla. I had problems with this option,
 then saw this: [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726387/4902724) You could use a setInterval and an ajax function to send data to the server at ever X seconts to make sure you're not losing something important.

Comment: yamboy1, if I don't put a return "somthing" statement in the onbeforeunload function it won't even display a message

Comment: @yamboy1, but if I put the return statement behind it it does execute the function, (by the way, alert isn't allowed while unloading the page)

Comment: @AhmedMahmud, yes it logs the messages I put in the beginning of the window.onbeforeunload method, it even logs it if I put a function in there with a console.log inside it, but if I put 'sendData()' inside it only console.log works, and when I put console.log in the end of the sendData() function it doesn't log anymore,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onunload` event in javascript like in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794528/run-javascript-code-only-if-beforeunload-function-returns-true).

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Are you sure ?'; 
  }

window.onunload = function () {
 sendData();
}
```

Comment: Ehm the second least character is a ) js gives a error that it's not supposed to be there, but if I remove it, it doesn't work.

Comment: I got it working!, sort of, there is a strange glitch, if I try to leave the page it will bring up the message: 'are you sure you want to leave?' if I click yes the first time it doesn't work and it will just quit, but if I click no, it spams another message and when I click yes the second time it works?!
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    sendData();
    return 'Are you sure ?'; 
  }


function sendData() {
  console.log("test"); .......

Comment: I just forgotten to remove the `);` .Answer modified @Floris

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a direct answer to the question, but it worked for me:
Instead of sending the data on pageonunload what didn't work, I tried to send data with an interval using XMLHttpRequest, which works perfectly.

Comment: It is more like a comment